# Pattern Matching with Even and Odd Cases

Tags: coq

Suppose I write a Fixpoint algorithm in Coq that sums up all the "halves" of a number:

```
Fixpoint sum_of_halves (a : nat) : nat :=
  match a with
  | 0 => 0
  | 2 * k => a + (sum_of_halves k)
  | S (2 * k)  => a + (sum_of_halves k)
  end.
```

Trying to evaluate the algorithm would get: `Error: Invalid notation for pattern.`

How can I get Coq to recognize that a is either an even or an odd number, and match it with either `2 * k` or `S (2 * k)`?

Comment: There are quite a few questions discussing this, use the search function!

Comment: I searched pattern matching on even, odd, or both. I could not find any sufficient answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Coq can only `match` on constructors. `nat` has two constructors, `O` and `S`, so you cannot match on `2 * k`. You will have to use a non-`match` construct or a non-`nat` type or a different algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove that there are only three cases for a given natural number `a`.  Either `a` is 0, either `a` is the double of another number `k` and `k < a`, or `a` is the double `k` + 1 and `k < a`, that the three cases are exclusive (this is important, otherwise making pattern matching possible would lead to an inconistency).

Fortunately, all this can be done.  It is a bit advanced Coq programming, but it is somehow already done in `ZArith`.  Here is a solution.

First note that the other number is already provided by one of the functions in the Coq library, `div2`.

```
Require Import Arith Nat.

Definition cases_div2 (a : nat) :
  {k : nat | a = 2 * k /\ k < a}+{k : nat | a = S (2 * k) /\ k < a}+{a=0}.
destruct a as [ | a'].
  right; reflexivity.
case_eq (odd (S a')); intros odd_a.
  left; right; exists (div2 (S a')); rewrite (div2_odd (S a')) at 1.
  split.
    rewrite odd_a; simpl b2n; ring.
  apply lt_div2; auto with arith.
left; left; exists (div2 (S a')); rewrite (div2_odd (S a')) at 1.
split.
   rewrite odd_a; simpl b2n; ring.
 apply lt_div2; auto with arith.
Defined.
```

Now, you can pattern match on your number a using `cases_div2`, but it is still not enough to define your function, because recursion using `Fixpoint` relies on recursive calls happening on the predecessor, and here `k` cannot be written as a predecessor pattern that will work for any input `a`.  You need a stronger kind of recursion.  I usually rely on `Function` or `Fix` for this kind of strong recursion.  Here is an example with `Fix`

```
Definition sum_of_halves : nat -> nat :=
  Fix Arith.Wf_nat.lt_wf (fun _ => nat)
   (fun a (sum_of_halves' : forall y, y < a -> nat) =>
   match cases_div2 a with
   | inright h => 0
   | inleft (inl (exist _ k (conj keq klt))) => 
        a + sum_of_halves' k klt
   | inleft (inr (exist _ k (conj keq klt))) =>
        a + sum_of_halves' k klt
   end).
```

Then to reason about `sum_of_halves` you will need to reason by well founded induction and use `Fix_eq`.

This is one possibility.